# Suggestion for new tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I think a new tag, "strimmer", should be added, at least as an alias for some other tag.  It's a common British term for "String trimmer" or "Edge trimmer" or "Weed-whacker", and I have found myself wanting to tag my question with this on a couple of occasions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know if "strimmer" is just a portmanteau of "string" and "trimmer", or if it was used as a brand name in Britain at one point?

Comment: Well, [Wiktionary says both](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/strimmer); it was used as a trademark, which was presumably a portmanteau of "string trimmer".  Personally I think it's a more catchy word to use.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

They seem to be mentioned widely enough to warrant a tag; the proper name for them seems to be [string trimmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_trimmer), with strimmer being one of the synonyms, so I'll create them and add the tag to your post (expect a couple of edits as I do it). Update: done!

I'll also go through and retag some older questions that could use the new tag.

Comment: Cheers for the update (though the 'proper' name in the UK is 'strimmer' :-P)!